# Phonegap Application Deploy to Simulator in Blackberry

Tags: cordova, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I have tried to create a Phonegap application in Blackberry. I followed each and every step given in this [Phonegap guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_blackberry_index.md.html). But when I came to this step

**Deploy to Simulator**

`ant target load-device`

I hit a roadblock. Does anybody have an idea? How to load to the device using `ant target`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target is just a placeholder for either blackberry, playbook, or qnx. Use blackberry if you are deploying BB OS 5-7, playbook for the Playbook, and qnx for the new BlackBerry 10. In addition, make sure your device is connected to your computer via usb. Also, if you want to deploy to simulator, you should use:

```
ant target load-simulator
```

Comment: Please let me know how you configure Sample project property file ...can you explain this in brif